# Find latest time a machine changed transition

Tags: sql, kql

I have a table that looks like this

[image]

I want to obtain a table that shows the SerialNumber, State and Transition_Date for the last time a table changed state, so something like this

[image]

the issue is that if I do something like Max(Transition_Date) by SerialNumber then I get the correct results but I am not able to see the state

[image]

But if I do Max(TransitionDate) by SerialNumber, State then I get the latest date for each state which is also not what I want.

Can someone help me? I don't mind on what version of SQL or Kusto I get a reply, this is just to give me an idea of how to find a solution for this.

Comment: Could you add what you want as the output? Last time the machine changed is surely the max(transition_date) for each serialNumber... so I'm thinking you must want something else.

Comment: @ColinRooney What I want is to get the SerialNumber, State and Transition_Date for the latest state.

Comment: @ColinRooney Sorry, I found some issues with my current explanation so I've changed it to make it more clear

Comment: okay, I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With KQL, you can use the `arg_max()` aggregation function:

```
datatable(SerialNumber:int, State:string, Transition_Date:datetime)
[
    123, "A", datetime(2020-07-12),
    123, "B", datetime(2021-05-06),
    321, "B", datetime(2021-06-06),
    321, "C", datetime(2021-05-05),
    321, "A", datetime(2021-02-01),
]
| summarize arg_max(Transition_Date, *) by SerialNumber
```

| SerialNumber | Transition_Date | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-05-06 00:00:00.0000000 | B |
| 321 | 2021-06-06 00:00:00.0000000 | B |

Comment: And if this isn't a one-time query, then you might want to look into [Materialized Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview), that will do `summarize arg_max(...) by ...` continuously as new data arrives. This will significantly improve your query performance, and reduce costs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there must be an easier way but all I could think of was...

```
WITH lastChange AS (
SELECT serial_number, MAX(transition_date) as last_transition
FROM test
GROUP BY serial_number
)
SELECT t.serial_number, t.machine_state, t.transition_date
FROM Test t
INNER JOIN lastChange c ON c.serial_number = t.serial_number AND t.transition_date = c.last_transition
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer within Kusto

```
TableName
| summarize arg_max(Transition_Date, State) by SerialNumber
```

this will give you the maximum date, and state for each SerialNumber (Machine)